# Setting a default value in a Kotlin data class conditionally

Tags: java, kotlin

I am trying to implement an interface in Kotlin, and basically what I am trying to do is say: "If the value `atb` if null/not set, then set it to `bugId`".

Here is the Kotlin interface I am trying to implement

```kotlin
interface Incident {

    @get:NotNull
    @get:Past
    val incidentDate: LocalDateTime

    @get:NotNull
    val source: String

    @get:NotNull
    @get:Positive
    val bugId: Int

    @get:NotNull
    @get:Pattern(
        regexp = "FOO|BAZ",
        message = "'\${validatedValue}' not allowed. Must be one of : {regexp}"
    )
    val pillar: String

    @get:Positive
    val atb: Int

}
```

And here is how I am trying to implement it:

```kotlin
data class PSR (
    @JsonDeserialize(using = DoubleToInt::class)
    override val bugId: Int,

    @JsonDeserialize(using = EpochToLocalDateTime::class)
    override val incidentDate: LocalDateTime,

    override val pillar: String,

    @JsonDeserialize(using = DoubleToInt::class)
    override val atb: Int = bugId,

    ) : Incident {
    override val source: String = "PSR"
}
```

The problem is I am trying to deserialize this data from JSON and when I do, I get the following (understandable) error:

```
Instantiation of [simple type, class com.company.models.spreadsheets.psr.PSR] value failed for JSON property atb due to missing (therefore NULL) value for creator parameter atb which is a non-nullable type
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN] (through reference chain: com.company.models.spreadsheets.psr.PSR["atb"])
```

I've given the equivalent java code below that achieves what I want. How can I do this in Kotlin (and keep the benefits of a data class)?

```java
    class PERF implements Incident {
        private final LocalDateTime incidentDate;
        private final Integer bugId;
        private final String pillar;
        private final Integer atb;

        public PERF(LocalDateTime incidentDate, Integer bugId, String pillar, Integer atb) {
            this.bugId = bugId;
            this.atb = atb == null ? bugId: atb;
            this.incidentDate = incidentDate;
            this.pillar = pillar;
        }

        @NotNull
        @Override
        public LocalDateTime getIncidentDate() {
            return incidentDate;
        }

        @Override
        public int getBugId() {
            return bugId;
        }

        @NotNull
        @Override
        public String getPillar() {
            return pillar;
        }

        @Override
        public int getAtb() {
            return atb;
        }
        @Override
        public String getSource() {
            return "PERF"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Jackson, just create a secondary constructor and mark *that* as `JsonCreator` instead. Have the secondary constructor delegate to the primary one.

```
data class PSR (
    override val bugId: Int,
    override val incidentDate: LocalDateTime,
    override val pillar: String,
    override val atb: Int = bugId,
    ) : Incident {

    @JsonCreator
    constructor(
        @JsonDeserialize(using = DoubleToInt::class)
        @JsonProperty("bugId")
        bugId: Int,

        @JsonDeserialize(using = EpochToLocalDateTime::class)
        @JsonProperty("incidentDate")
        incidentDate: LocalDateTime,

        @JsonProperty("pillar")
        pillar: String,

        @JsonDeserialize(using = DoubleToInt::class)
        @JsonProperty("atb")
        atb: Int?,
    ): this(bugId, incidentDate, pillar, atb ?: bugId)

    override val source: String = "PSR"
}
```

Comment: It was that constructor annotation I was missing - thanks